# Session ID of md5(time())

Tags: php, sql, security

I have the code:

```
if ($usernamelogin == $dbusername && $passwordlogin == $dbpassword)
{
    $hash = md5(time());
    mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users SET sessionid='$hash' WHERE username='$usernamelogin' AND password='$passwordlogin'");
    $_SESSION['id'] = $hash;
    $_SESSION['un'] = $usernamelogin;
}
else 
{
    echo ('Wrong username or password.');
}
```

I'm then using $sessionid, the SQL sessionid, and the usernames to verify if a user is real. This means that, assuming I have protection against an SQL injection, there are relatively few security risks, right?

I came here to ask, because this seems like an overly simple solution to a complex problem. All of the documents and websites I've been to have implemented much more complex, confusing, and sometimes insecure methods of verifying if a user is logged in.

Is this secure?

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing passwords in plain text in the database? If you are then **NO** you're not secure. Also, if you're not using SSL, the session is can be intercepted. Even if you are, many "best practice" guides suggest updating session id frequently (5-10 mins). Finally, why pick a predictable session id? If someone can guess roughly when a session was created, they can guess the id (to withing a small range). use a GUID/UUID

Comment: I haven't switched that yet, but no I will NOT be storing them in plain text. I'm still in the development phase.

Comment: Oh and you're also susceptible to SQL injection. Try a password of `pass'; DROP TABLE users--` (Ok, don't but you get the point).

Comment: *"websites ... have implemented ... sometimes insecure methods"* - insecure, according to whom?

Comment: @Basic Okay, I switched to GUID and I will switch to a hash on the passwords(obviously), and I can update frequently, plus I'd have a password check on any page where a user could really do something dumb(money is involved, gotta be sure). How do I use SSL? I understand SSL is a secure network, but do I need to specify that in my code or on my server settings or where?

Comment: @DCoder I didn't mean the websites themselves, but before tonight I was thinking I could use the user IP as a session variable to secure the website(though I had my doubts about this). I'm learning more and more to take all the code I find on the internet with a grain of salt.

Comment: @JamesG. What will be your encryption method?

Comment: "How do I use SSL?" is a very broad question, and based on your posting history I do not see this endeavour of yours ending well. You shouldn't deal with money until you learn quite a bit more about how the web security works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `md5(time())` to generate a session id, this is not secure. The time is liner and can be guessable, for example some websites show when the user has loged-in, you could use this information and brute-force to hijack his session id.

Second thing, you can also brute-frose on random time and there is a great chance you will get some random user session id. Also,  there is a good chance that two users will have the same second thing is two users will have the same session id if they login at the same time.

Have a look at this great talk ([DEFCON 18: How I Met Your Girlfriend 1/3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEmO7wQKCMw)), I  watch it a long time a go, I can't remember the details, but I remember the speaker made series point about session weaknesses. Also, see [OWASP wiki](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page), it has great resources on web security and sessions security.

Comment: This would be solved by the check with the usernames(they wouldn't have the same session id and username, so there was no problem), though if you check the comments on the OP, I'm no longer using md5(time()) anyways. I'll watch the video, and I've already been looking at the OWASP wiki. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesG. The whole point of a session Id is that it's the only thing a client needs to know... Otherwise, what's to stop me modifying the cookie/whatever you store in my browser to pretend to be someone else? You can't trust _anything_ provided by the client. Session ids _must_ be unique and unguessable

Answer (score 2):

Please don't take this the wrong way but if you don't understand SSL, you shouldn't be handling money.

SSL Is used to encrypt communication between the browser and the server. Without it, anyone on the networks between the browser and server can see every request/response sent in clear text - passwords, account ids, credit card numbers(?), etc.

This is the difference between `http://` addresses and `https://` addresses. It requires both server and code changes

The server needs a certificate from a trusted authority to enable SSL (and some config changes) but that's not enough. You also need to make sure your code does things like only issues [`secure` cookies - that is, cookies that can't be sent over `http`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly), should check SSL is enabled on incoming requests in case of server misconfiguration, etc, etc. It's a massive topic and I can't tell you enough in one answer to make you secure.

As an absolute minimum, your code should be secure against all the [OWASP Top 10 vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Table_of_Contents). This is the absolute bread and butter stuff for making any site secure.

You also need to read up on [SSL/TLS and encryption in general](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/encryption.htm). This will give you an overview of how handshakes/messages are passed back and forth.

Comment: I agree, the website will not be active until I know it is 100% secure. The site is not online, still in development. I want to make sure I understand security completely before anything will be public. Thanks.